# batch file variable issue

Tags: windows, batch-file

Batch newbie here. I have an issue with a variable not being captured correctly. I have SCCM Object variable's for ABC_RegionCode, ABC_DBNAME, ABC_Schema and srvpocWeb_%%% (where %%% equals one of 100's of regioncodes).

***My Question:***  How can i get this batch to pull the variable value for srvPocWeb_(ABC_RegionCode) if the Regioncode variable changes for each machine it runs on? I need the script to know that srvPocWeb_%1="%4" means i want the value of the variable to be stored in %4.

this script works fine if i just hardcode the full sitecode name rather than srvPocWeb_%1="%4". its almost as if batch cannot tell i want this translated to a string before reading it.

example.bat %ABC_RegionCode% %ABC_DBNAME% %ABC_SCHEMA% !srvPocWeb_%1! >> C:\test.txt

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Pull in variables from SCCM OBject - 

@echo set ABC_RegionCode="%1"
@echo set ABC_DBNAME="%2"
@echo set ABC_SCHEMA="%3"
@echo set srvPocWeb_%1="%4"



@echo "C:\Program Files\Application_%1\Database\Tools\Client\Client.exe" sourcepath="C:\Source" databasetype="oracle" databaseconnection="data Source=%2;User Id=%3;Password=!srvPocWeb_%1!" reportsfolderpath="C:\reports"

@echo "C:\Program Files\Application_%1\Database\Tools\Client\Client.exe" sourcepath="C:\Source" reImportBuild=true outputonly=false databasetype="oracle" databaseconnection="data Source=%2;User Id=%3;Password=!srvPocWeb_%1!" reportsfolderpath="C:\reports"
@echo All Done
```

Comment: I have great difficulty in working out what you are trying to do with what data. Please supply an example of the parameters you are supplying to your routine, the results you are obtaining and the result that you want. Simply use the `edit` facility under the tags to edit this data into your question - and remember to disguise the data supplied if appropriate.

Comment: i've attmpted to explain it a bit better. hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a confusion here. As I said you in your other question, you need to specify in which variables are stored each one of the values you want. If the Region code is stored in `ABC_RegionCode` variable, then its value is taken via `%ABC_RegionCode%`. In the `srvpocWeb_%%%` variable (where %%% equals one of 100's of regioncodes, and the specific region code is given by ABC_RegionCode variable) the *name* of the variable is `srvpocWeb_%ABC_RegionCode%` and its *value* is `!srvpocWeb_%ABC_RegionCode%!`. This way, you may modify your command-line this way:

```
example.bat %ABC_RegionCode% %ABC_DBNAME% %ABC_SCHEMA% !srvPocWeb_%ABC_RegionCode%! >> C:\test.txt
```

However, previous line works only if Delayed Expansion is active *at the moment previous line is executed*, and Delayed Expansion is *not* enabled in the command-line by default.

You must realize that `%1` have the value of the first parameter *inside the Batch file only*, **not** in the same line used to invoke the Batch file.

Another way to solve your problem is this:

```
example.bat %ABC_RegionCode% %ABC_DBNAME% %ABC_SCHEMA% >> C:\test.txt
```

Inside the Batch file, `%1` have *the value* of `ABC_RegionCode`, so you may get the rigth value of `srvPocWeb_%%%` variable this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set srvPocWeb=!srvPocWeb_%1!
```

PS - This problem should be followed in the same thread of the original question. It is a very bad idea to delete a question and post new details about the same topic in a new question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer (again) apreciate it.